# The differences between a normal map with dynamic map - automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

What are the differences between the codes below;

```
    List<Ogrenci> ogrenci = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader,   List<Ogrenci>>((dt.CreateDataReader()));

    var ogr = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<Ogrenci>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

When i try to use the code below;

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Ogrenci>().ForMember(dest => dest.Numarasi, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToInt32(src["Numara"])))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Adi, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToString(src["Ad"])))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Soyadi, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToString(src["Soyad"])));

        List<Ogrenci> ogrenci = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Ogrenci>>((dt.CreateDataReader()));
        var ogr = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<Ogrenci>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

I can not use use the code below;

```
  List<Ogrenci> ogrenci = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Ogrenci>>((dt.CreateDataReader()));
```

but i can use the code below ;

```
   var ogr = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<Ogrenci>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

What are your suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

DynamicMap in AutoMapper is used when you don't know the source type at compile time.  The reason you can't use

```
List<Ogrenci> ogrenci = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Ogrenci>>((dt.CreateDataReader()));
```

is because DynamicMap doesn't need you to specify the source type, only the destination type.

[AutoMapper features: Dynamic Mapping](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/)