# Inconsistent Mapping Behavior in AutoMapper 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, automapper-3

I've had issues with AutoMapper 3 mapping related entities from entity framework to a view model some of the time in MVC 5.  I'm using EF 6.1.1 to get the data, and a thin and light repository layer to centralize queries. That issue only seems to occur with mapping properties from entities under a root entity, but the problem is intermittent.  I've seen the behavior start working again after rebuilding the solution and the behavior break after rebuilding the solution without changing the code where the issue occurs.

I've tested this in the debugger and SQL profiler, and even when the data isn't showing up on the front end, I can see in the SQL profiler that Entity Framework is loading the related tables.

**Example mapping with the issue**

This code executes in the MVC controller after the data has been queried from the repository layer. The view model will then be passed off to the view for rendering.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, EventViewModel>()
    .ForMember(e => e.EventTitleId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.EventTitleType.EventTitleId));
EventViewModel model = Mapper.Map<Event, EventViewModel>(eventItem);

//Fix Up I had to implement to ensure the data gets into the property
model.EventTitleId = eventItem.EventTitleType.EventTitleId;
```

**Another example mapping with the issue**

Same basic execution path under a different controller action, same problem.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, EventViewModel>()
    .ForMember(l => l.EventTitle, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.EventTitleType.EventTitle.Title))
    .ForMember(l => l.EventType, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.EventTitleType.LkEventType.Title))
    .ForMember(l => l.LocationName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.LkLocation.LocationName));
IEnumerable<EventViewModel> eventList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Event>, IEnumerable<EventViewModel>>(events);
```

Again, sometimes the three properties get data, and sometimes they don't.

**Data Model**

This is what the Data Model looks like.

[image: The part of the edmx file with the data model for this question]

**Repository**

The repository layers wraps up the entity framework calls, but it does not abstract away the entity framework entities and the issues and benefits it has.  All repositories in the project inherit IRepository, and I'm using this layer to centralize query and business logic.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tools.Repository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic Repository Interface
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TClass">Class that the Repository is implemented for.</typeparam>
    public interface IRepository<TClass>
        where TClass : class 
    {
        void SaveChanges();
        TClass Find(params object[] keyValues);
        IEnumerable<TClass> GetAll();
        TClass Add(TClass itemToAdd);
        TClass Update(TClass itemToUpdate);
        TClass Remove(TClass itemToDelete);
    }
}
```

**Summary**

I don't believe this is an Entity Framework lazy loading issue, and after forcing EF to eager load the data, the problem persists.  The entities have the values in the debugger before mapping, but only sometimes will the value get mapped to the view model.  The most frustrating thing is that the issue does not seem to be caused by any changes I've made to the view model.

What can cause such inconsistent behavior?  I've had this problem with both AutoMapper 3.2.1 and 3.1.1.

Comment: Where do you execute the `Mapper.CreateMap` statements? I may be wrong, but it looks like you run them just before you perform the mapping. But they should run once at application startup. Now it's a matter of coincidence which one comes first.

Comment: I have generally run them just before I execute them. I did that in a previous app where I never had a problem, but I can put them in one central place.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it will solve your issue. There will be one mapping then between `Event` and `EventViewModel`, so you must choose which one it's gonna be (or combine the mappings).

Comment: You are right! Whatever map is first created is used for the lifetime off the application. I need you to write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you create (configure) the mappings right before you use them. Now it's a matter of coincidence which mapping is created first and, thus, will prevail.

The [AutoMapper documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) says:

> If you're using the static Mapper method, configuration should only happen once per AppDomain. That means the best place to put the configuration code is in application startup, such as the Global.asax file for ASP.NET applications.

This means you have only one mapping between `Event` and `EventViewModel`, which probably should be a combination of the two you have now.

By the way, you can execute occasional mappings by [`DynamicMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489547/861716).